# Firebase Reporting Options

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All my app's data is stored in Firebase. I'd like to build some reports with my data that aren't necessarily accessible through the web/app front-end. I don't see any good options for this in the Console. Has anyone found a good reporting solution for Firebase? I am looking for something like Crystal Reports or just an easy way to render Firebase data based on a query.
Thanks,
Rima.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Can you be more specific as to what kind of reports you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. I'd like to build reports on top of my data, something that I would do in Crystal Reports for example if it was a SQL data source. Or MongoDB has it's own suite of reporting tools. http://jsonstudio.com/mongodb-reporting-5-minutes/

Comment: Firebase has query functions built in so getting data out of Firebase would generally be done through those. I don't believe there are any reporting tools available that's going to give you the data you want.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/arps42/reportingbi_tools_and_firestore/

Answer (score 1):

I found a issue with the solution above.  Firebase stores its data in JSON format, which cannot be consumed by solutions such as BigQuery, because it is expecting JSONL format and you get an error.  It beats me why Google are not providing an elegant solution when integrating between two of their products, but I believe they have something planned.

Comment: I am also very surprised at the lack of proper reporting tools for Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not have any "built-in" reporting tools other than the defined querying APIs.

If your database is small, you dump the JSON from the Firebase Console and then manually run analysis on it.

If your database is large, you can upgrade to the Flame or Blaze plans and sign up for daily private backups. This will create a JSON dump in the background without affecting your database performance and store it in the cloud. You could then use tools to grab that dump and perform advanced reporting on it.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Via BigQuery**

> Official Docs:
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore
>
> Codelab Walkthrough:
>   https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/modern-data-pipeline-firestore-bigquery-dataflow-templates/index.html?index=..%2F..next17
>
> Connect whatever BI tool you want to BigQuery. Google Data Studio is
>   free as is Metabase. Almost every Enterprise BI tool has a BigQuery
>   connector.

From https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/arps42/reportingbi_tools_and_firestore/

**2) Via "Custom Data Sources"**

Cloud Firestore (and probably Realtime-Db) has a RESTFUL API. Many popular reporting tools support "custom", "restful", "ajax", and/or "HTTP" sources.

You should search your favorite reporting tools, and internet search accordingly.

I can see that Stimulsoft seems to support custom/RESTFUL sources. A PowerBI data connector seems to provide a lot of latitude - https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors

Of course, this means that you need to create several data sources, and they probably won't be as optimised as a built-in source type. For example, the report engine probably won't know how to translate any front-end UI filters into custom-source query filters. Perhaps some platforms support the ability for you to create your own adaptors.

Comment: Also, https://firebase.cooladata.com/, but it might not work with the newest firestore